# Is it possible to set up a service/application like Jotti's malware scan?

Tags: anti-virus, services, malware, bots

I would like to scan files that are under 500/100 MB. Sadly, Jotti only scans files up to 25 MB. Is it possible to set up a service like that at home?

The only way I know to run so many anti-virus engines, is using virtual machines. But that would cost a lot of memory, and a lot of work to set this up.

(**Nutshell: I would like to build/set up a virus scan bot with several AV engines.**
Also: It would be used only for personal/home use, not commercial.)
[Jotti's Malware Scan](http://virusscan.jotti.org/en)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use virtual machines. Just use the command line scanners, call them via a script and parse their output.